# Speech synthesis in MATLAB : diphthongs

Tags: synthesis, speech, phonetics

I am trying to generate vowels on MATLAB by using source-filter model. In case of monophthongs I'm using Rosenberg pulse as my source signal and then this source signal is convoluted with sounds generated from formants. Basically I'm using the approach used in the following project http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45449-vowel-synthesis

Now I'm trying to do synthesis of diphthongs which are basically generated by gliding from one monophthong to another. I've tried weighted-average but it's not working. So how can I model this transitioning from formants of one monophthong to other to generate the IPA diphthongs ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [formant synthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formant_synthesis), this should be mostly a question of finding the correct transition duration T1 between the two formant configurations, i.e.:

- t=0 to t=T1: linear transition from F_vowel1_i to F_vowel2_i
- t=T1 to t=T1+T2: constant formant frequency for a duration T2

with i is the index of the i-th formant.

The linear formant transition should not sound so bad (you can try with a non-linear transition, such as a spline), and then changing the fundamental frequency and the loudness during the transition will make it more alive.